# Can I activate Window 8 en with my en_gb key?

Tags: windows, windows-8, product-key

I am a student and I got a key through DreamSpark/MSDNAA for "Microsoft Windows 8 Professional 32/64-bit (English-Great Britain)".
I tried to download the iso with Secure Download Manager, but after 4 hours of struggling a I couldn't get even 7% of the file. So I am downloading it from a different source, but It isn't an en_gb version, "Microsoft Windows 8 Professional x64 MSDN ENG" (en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso). 
My question is, Can I activate the English version of Windows 8 with a en_gb key? 
(I think English means en_us)

Comment: Yes...of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the language will be an issue, but the fact your now downloading a different edition (MSDN) would be.

I would instead try another pc to do the download.  Or if you know someone who has successfully burnt the dreamspark ISO to DVD you can just legally use that.

Comment: I don't know, the download with the Secure Download Manager (I am forced to use this. *.sdx file provides the source) is unreliable, slow and always stop the download without a word. I simply can't download the "purchased" version from MSDNAA.

Comment: But the secure download manager isn't tied to one single PC is it?  I.e. its installable on another PC with a hopefully better internet connection :)

Comment: My internet connection works just fine. I can download anything with 900-1200 kb/s speed.

Comment: Well, then contact the site, as the problem with the SDM stopping is their end.  But using a friends pc is worth a shot surely.

Comment: @cjb110 - If you are not aware of how `Secure Download Manager` works best not comment on it. The author's connection is likely to blame ( forced proxy, ect ) not possible to say why the download fails, without more information.  Besides its not actually even installed.  The problem is not on the DreamSpark side.

Comment: I don't think this edition would be a problem wither. As long as he is downloading Pro edition, source should not matter AFAIK.